# Module js import/export issue (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to teach SPA in Laravel + Vue.

I have a few pretty simpe components.

```
<template>
    <p>Home</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Home'
    }
</script>
```

Also, I have a router file

```
import Home from '../pages/home.vue';
import Profile from '../pages/profile.vue';


export let routes = [
    {
        path : '/home',
        component : Home
    },
    {
        path : '/profile',
        component : Profile
    }
];
```

npm run dev  - "build successfull"

I've attached router-link tags and placed router-view. 
But there is just . It's gives the same result with "out of the box" Laravel example-component.vue .

It seems there is somethng wrong with import settings in my component, but what?

Comment: You have to initialize the router, check the [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html).

Comment: @yuriy636 I've found the problem. Silly me))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the project structure. 
I have a router/routes.js and app.js file

In app.js I import routes from routes.js and do new VueRouter.

The error was:

```
import {routes} from './router/routes';
let router = new VueRouter(routes);
```

Should be

```
import {routes} from './router/routes';
let router = new VueRouter({routes});
```